# JavaScript creating a radio button and a label

Tags: javascript, radio-button, label

I am trying to create a radio button and a label with JavaScript and I got the radio button working, but the label doesn't appear next to it and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. This is my code:

```
        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        document.body.appendChild(x);


        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode("Label text");
        y.textContent = "Label text";
        y.setAttribute("for", "lord");
        y.appendChild(t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the label to the body but your code is appending it as child of radio button

```js
const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
x.setAttribute("id", "lord");
document.body.appendChild(x);


const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
const t = document.createTextNode("Label text");
y.textContent = "Label text";
y.setAttribute("for", "lord");
document.body.appendChild(t);
```

Comment: If I am to put multiple radio buttons each with a label one under the other, can you give me a hint what I can use to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For each radio button and label , create a div, wrap the radio button and label in that div , then append each of those div to the body

Comment: Alright, thank you very much :) I will post another question if there are any problems with implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

yo have to apppend to de document, like the radio button

```js
document.body.appendChild(y);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for the help:))